# Programming a module to handle multiple button clicks vb

Tags: vb.net

I'm programming a tic-tac-toe game using a Windows form. I have a 'table' for the playing field and buttons for the icons. I have used a module which I want to handle each button click instead of writing out code for each button.

Code:

```
Private Sub Btn_Box6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Box6.Click
        ChangeTxt()
    End Sub
```

(***Example of one of the button click conditions***)

```
Sub ChangeTxt()
        If Form1.Active_PlayerTxt.Text = "X" Then
            PlayerOne = True
        ElseIf Form1.Active_PlayerTxt.Text = "O" Then
            PlayerTwo = True
        Else
            MsgBox("Please enter X or O to decide the player!")
        End If
        If PlayerOne = True Then
            Form1.Btn_Box1.Text = "X"
        ElseIf PlayerTwo = True Then
            Form1.Btn_Box1.Text = "O"
        Else
            MsgBox("Please enter X or O to decide the player!")
        End If
        Form1.Active_PlayerTxt.Text = ""
        PlayerOne = False
        PlayerTwo = False
    End Sub
```

So basically as you can see, this currently only changes btn_box1, but I want it to change each separate button (btn_box2) when they are clicked instead of just changing btn_box1. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Try having ChangeText take a Button as its argument, instead of having no arguments, and inside that method, you can check which Button you need to update.  The Sender object from each event handler will be that Button, so you can pass it into ChangeText.  Even cleaner is to just have one event handler that handles all button click events, which calls ChangeText.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple way of doing a tic-tac-toe game:

1. Check who is the current player : X or O.
2. When the current player clicks the button he wants to, change the text of that button (first check if it isnt clicked already).
3. Update the current player etc..

You can do something like this :

```
' Create an enum to represent the current player.
Public Enum CurrentPlayer
    X
    O
End Enum

' Create an "instance" of the enum.
Public cPlayer As CurrentPlayer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Lets say the first player is X.
    cPlayer = CurrentPlayer.X

    ' Reset the text of the buttons.
    ' You can do this using the properties of the buttons in the designer.
    For Each btn As Button In Me.Controls
        btn.Text = ""
    Next

End Sub

' Occures when the first button is clicked.
Private Sub ButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click
    ' Calls the funciton and passing the current button (byref).
    CheckText(sender)
End Sub

' Passing an argument byref does not create a copy
' of the argument, but sends the "real" one.
Public Sub CheckText(ByRef btn As Button)

    ' First check if the current button is "free".
    If btn.Text = "" Then

        ' Change the text of the button according to the current player.
        Select Case cPlayer
            Case CurrentPlayer.X
                btn.Text = "x"
                cPlayer = CurrentPlayer.O
            Case CurrentPlayer.O
                btn.Text = "O"

                ' Changes the current player.
                cPlayer = CurrentPlayer.X
        End Select
    Else
        MsgBox("This button is already used!")
    End If
End Sub
```

I'l let you do the function that looks for a winner :)

Hoped it helped.

Comment: `Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click`, etc, etc.